# A resource reference binding could not be found

Tags: java, web-services, websphere-8

Currently I tried to upgrade a webservice system from Websphere 6 to Websphere 8.5.
However I got this kind of issues

> CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the /wsContext resource reference, defined for the  component.

Inside the source code, that part only contains

> @Resource
>   WebServiceContext wsContext;

This error will be gone if I switch class loader policy from parent last to parent first.
However, do you know is there anyway to avoid this error with "parent last"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application must contain a JAR with the `WebServiceContext` class, which is preventing the server from recognizing this type as a "builtin" object for it to inject because you're using "parent last". If you must use "parent last", then your options are:

1. Remove the JAR containing `WebServiceContext` from your application. This option assumes you need "parent last" in order to override some other class from the server but not webservices classes.
2. Remove the `@Resource` annotation. This option assumes you are trying to override the webservice implementation.  In that case, you can't rely on container injection.

Comment: Thanks, but the WebServiceContext is inside jaxws-api.jar file, and this jar cannot be removed because it contained many important classes.

Comment: Those classes/interfaces should all be provided by the application server. Why do you need to override them?

Comment: I tried to removed all  jaxws-api.jar jar file and it throws the new exception: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=com/sun/xml/ws/server/AbstractWebServiceContext, method=getEndpointReference([Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)Ljavax/xml/ws/EndpointReference;, pc=0

Comment: This probably means you now have an "incomplete" override. For example, since you're no longer overriding javax.xml.ws, you're now loading something else like org.w3c twice (once from the server via javax.xml.ws and again from some API JAR in your application). I recommend removing all API JARs from your application.