# Websphere, Spring WS A resource reference binding could not be found

Tags: spring, websphere, spring-ws, websphere-8

I am trying to deploy Spring web application using Spring Web Services on Websphere 8. Deploy to Tomcat works without any problem but with Websphere I needed to add jaxws-rt (this wasn't needed for Tomcat, but also with it is working) and after that I am still getting on WAS:

```
CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the following resource
references [com.sun.xml.ws.transport.tcp.servicechannel.ServiceChannelWSImpl/wsContext,     
com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.RegistrationRequesterPortTypeImpl/wsContext,
com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.RegistrationPortTypeImpl/wsContext,
com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.ActivationRequesterPortTypeImpl/wsContext,
com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.RegistrationCoordinatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext,
com.sun.xml.ws.mex.server.MEXEndpoint/wsContext,
com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.CoordinatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext,
com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.ActivationCoordinatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext,
com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.CompletionInitiatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext,
com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.ParticipantPortTypeImpl/wsContext,
com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.CompletionCoordinatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext]
```

How to specify reference bindings?

I also see another error during deployin SystemErr:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load
webapp: Failed to load webapp: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer not a subtype
```

But I am not sure if this is somehow connected with reference binding problem.

Comment: Can you see if this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798006/a-resource-reference-binding-could-not-be-found#20831904 ? The other question didn't have much detail, so I'm not sure if this is the same issue or not.

Comment: The second error solved- the problem was that I was using Spring Java config with Servlet 3 capabilities and Websphere somehow doesn't load all implementations of `WebApplicationInitializer` interface. Only the one which is annotated with `@HandlesTypes(WebApplicationInitializer.class`). When I use multiple annotations Websphere is still loading only main confing. When I configured servlets in the main config, there was problem with Spring security, so I ended up with web.xml. But the problem with resources remains. I don't use parent last and jaxws-rt jar is required by Websphere.

Comment: The first problem was really solved with using parent first class loading.