# Websphere Application Server, Jackson 1.9 and User Transaction. Cant find a working setting

Tags: websphere, classloader, websphere-8

I'm trying to deploy a war to Websphere that is using and packaging Jackson 1.9.
It is also using usertransactions in a CDI interceptor

If I set bot WAR and EAR classloaders to parent last, the app won't start

```
A resource reference binding could not be found for the following resource references [a.b.c.MyInterceptor/utx], defined for the foobar.war component.
```

If I change the WAR classloader to parent last, the application starts but then Jackson 1.5 of Websphere is used resulting in MethodNotFound exceptions.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.getFields()Ljava/util/Iterator;
```

I'm a bit lost. What do I have to do to make Websphere behave like any other non idiotic server and create whatever bindings he needs to create while still using my bundled libraries when provided.

Comment: maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798006/a-resource-reference-binding-could-not-be-found, still looking into it

Comment: Can you post a.b.c.MyInterceptor code where are you using CDI and UserTransaction?

Comment: Jackson and Jersey are bundled with WAS, maybe try to disable them and create shared library with yours libraries. Check this post maybe it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684958/jax-rs-jersey-2-10-support-in-websphere-8/24713878#24713878

Comment: Thanks, it was elated to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798006/a-resource-reference-binding-could-not-be-found, so a classloading problem. Gas info was helpful nonetheless, thanks