# WAS 8.5, How to avoid annotation scanning?

Tags: websphere, jax-ws, websphere-8

We deploy a web app on WAS 8.5.0.0, we're using PARENT_LAST class loader(we have to for some reason), during the startup, there're some warnings:

```
[12/16/14 17:19:15:088 CST] 00000048 InjectionProc E   CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the com.sun.xml.ws.transport.tcp.servicechannel.ServiceChannelWSImpl/wsContext resource reference, defined for the MyProjectName component.
[12/16/14 17:19:15:089 CST] 00000048 InjectionProc E   CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.RegistrationRequesterPortTypeImpl/wsContext resource reference, defined for the MyProjectName component.
[12/16/14 17:19:15:090 CST] 00000048 InjectionProc E   CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.RegistrationPortTypeImpl/wsContext resource reference, defined for the MyProjectName component.
[12/16/14 17:19:15:090 CST] 00000048 InjectionProc E   CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.ActivationRequesterPortTypeImpl/wsContext resource reference, defined for the MyProjectName component.
[12/16/14 17:19:15:091 CST] 00000048 InjectionProc E   CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.RegistrationCoordinatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext resource reference, defined for the MyProjectName component.
[12/16/14 17:19:15:092 CST] 00000048 InjectionProc E   CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the com.sun.xml.ws.mex.server.MEXEndpoint/wsContext resource reference, defined for the MyProjectName component.
[12/16/14 17:19:15:092 CST] 00000048 InjectionProc E   CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.CoordinatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext resource reference, defined for the MyProjectName component.
[12/16/14 17:19:15:093 CST] 00000048 InjectionProc E   CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.ActivationCoordinatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext resource reference, defined for the MyProjectName component.
[12/16/14 17:19:15:093 CST] 00000048 InjectionProc E   CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.ParticipantPortTypeImpl/wsContext resource reference, defined for the MyProjectName component.
[12/16/14 17:19:15:094 CST] 00000048 InjectionProc E   CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.CompletionInitiatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext resource reference, defined for the MyProjectName component.
[12/16/14 17:19:15:095 CST] 00000048 InjectionProc E   CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.CompletionCoordinatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext resource reference, defined for the MyProjectName component.
```

Right after these warnings, there's an exception:

```
[12/16/14 17:19:15:213 CST] 00000048 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl populateJavaNameSpace SRVE8084E: An unexpected internal server error occurred while populating the namespace.
                                 com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the following resource references [com.sun.xml.ws.transport.tcp.servicechannel.ServiceChannelWSImpl/wsContext, com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.RegistrationRequesterPortTypeImpl/wsContext, com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.RegistrationPortTypeImpl/wsContext, com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.ActivationRequesterPortTypeImpl/wsContext, com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.RegistrationCoordinatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext, com.sun.xml.ws.mex.server.MEXEndpoint/wsContext, com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.CoordinatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext, com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.coord.ActivationCoordinatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext, com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.ParticipantPortTypeImpl/wsContext, com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.CompletionInitiatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext, com.sun.xml.ws.tx.webservice.member.at.CompletionCoordinatorPortTypeImpl/wsContext], defined for the MyProjectName component.
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionProcessor.resolveInjectionBindings(InjectionProcessor.java:1208)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorContextImpl.processBindings(InjectionProcessorContextImpl.java:56)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processBindings(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:807)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processInjectionMetaData(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:539)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.SharedInjectionEngineImpl.processInjectionMetaData(SharedInjectionEngineImpl.java:208)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.process(ReferenceContextImpl.java:835)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.populateJavaNameSpace(WebAppImpl.java:1112)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:328)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1170)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:769)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2172)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:994)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1783)
```

Sorry for the super long log info, basically, it's saying `"CWNEN0044E: A resource reference binding could not be found for the following resource references..."`, and the classes mentioned, like "`ServiceChannelWSImpl`", are all in the `webservice-rt-2.0.1.jar`

If I remove `webservice-rt-2.0.1.jar` and `webservice-api-2.0.1.jar`(and my classes which are dependent on these 2 jars), then the error is gone.

I google it, and it seems related to annotation scanning, so I update my `MANIFEST.MF`, and add:

```
Ignore-Scanning-Archives: webservices-api-2.0.1.jar, webservices-rt-2.0.1.jar
```

But this doesn't work, the error is still there.

Any other suggestions? I'm out of ideas, could some WAS expert please help?

**[updated]**
here is the web.xml(sorry I have to remove company relevant info )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    id="project-1" 
    version="3.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

  <display-name>project-1</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.mh.proj1.server.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.mh.proj1.spring.ApplicationContextHolder</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>proj1decision</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>
    <param-value>com.mh.proj1.exceptions.WAEExceptionMapper,com.mh.proj1.exceptions.GenericExceptionMapper</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CALC WS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CALC WS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
</web-app>
```

and the annotation used in the class:

```
@Component("CalcWS")
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.a.b.BaseWS", targetNamespace = "http://driver.abc.com/", serviceName = "BaseWSService", portName = "BaseWSPort", wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/BaseWSService.wsdl")
public class CalcWS implements BaseWS {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSphere provides JAX-WS runtime. So I'd suggest you to remove any JAX-WS related jars from your application and use WebSphere provided implementation. See if you still will have errors.

If you want to use third party provider you will need to disable WebSphere JAX-WS runtime for your application.

To turn off annotation scanning at the application level, set the `DisableIBMJAXWSEngine` property in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` of a WAR file or EJB module to true. Example:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
DisableIBMJAXWSEngine: true
```

Check for details this page: [Using a third-party JAX-WS web services engine](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-0-24-10-1&lang=en)

Comment: thank you for the reply, we already added DisableIBMJAXWSEngine: true in our MANIFEST.MF, but it doesn't help, we still run into the same error.

Comment: @morven Check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20831904/3701228. But did you try to remove webservices jars and use WAS built in engine?

Comment: Gas, I did try to remove webservice-rt-2.0.1.jar and webservice-api-2.0.1.jar, but it caused an error that WSServlet cannot be found, I  found there is a reference in web.xml, <servlet><servlet-name>xxx</servlet-name><servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class><load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup></servlet>. How to deal with this error?

Comment: @morven Are your web services defined with the `@WebService` annotation and is your `web.xml` 3.0 version? If yes, comment out that servlet from `web.xml` it shouldn't be needed in the JAX-WS compliant container. Maybe add `web.xml` and sample of your service class to the question.

Comment: Thank you Gas, I'll update the post when I get to the office tomorrow. About what you said that we don't need web.xml conf if we use annotation, does it apply to all servers(like Tomcat or something), or it only applies to WAS? Sorry if it's a stupid question,  I lack of the relevant knowledge.

Comment: @morven It applies to all Java EE servers, like WebSphere, JBoss, WebLogic, etc... Tomcat is just a web container, where you have to code/config all by yourself. If you are looking for lightweight server for development use [WebSphere Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/websphere-liberty/). It is almost as light as Tomcat but Java EE web profile certified.

Comment: Gas, I updated the post, could you please help to check if I can remove WSServlet and WSServletContextListener from the web.xml. After they're removed, how to check if the web service works, when I try to view wsdl via browser, I always run into 401 Unauthorized error.

Comment: @morven Your service should be available under `http://host:port/context/BaseWSService` and if you add `?wsdl` it should respond with the `wsdl` file. Not authorized error is related to the Spring security, so you have to check that, as I don't see Java EE security tags in `web.xml`.

Comment: @morven The other thing I see, is resteasy, which also might be a problem later on, since WebSphere is using Apache Wink as Jax-RS provider. In general, if you develop for WebSphere you should use full WebSphere or WebSphere Liberty as dev environment to avoid such migration issues.

Comment: Thank you for the patience, http://host:port/context/BaseWSService?wsdl return 404. Yes, I do have restful api,and it works fine on WAS, I can test it via Advanced REST Client.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72667/discussion-between-gas-and-morven).

Comment: @morven Check the chat.