# Seeing Websphere class instead of a class in one of my app's jars

Tags: jar, configuration, websphere, classloader

I'm having what seems to be a classloader/jar issue. Websphere 7, JDK 6.
Talking to a webservice works fine when the code is running in a simple, standalone Java class.

```
  ((WSBindingProvider) docManClient).setOutboundHeaders(Headers.create(otAuthElement));
```

In the debugger, the docManClient object has this toString():

```
   JAX-WS RI 2.1.4-b01-: Stub for http://innov15.ncr.pwgsc.gc.ca/innov15_cws/DocumentManagement.svc
```

The class path includes jaxws-rt-2.1.4.jar.

When the code is running inside Websphere, the cast fails.

```
  ((WSBindingProvider) docManClient).setOutboundHeaders(Headers.create(otAuthElement)); 
  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy484 incompatible with com.sun.xml.ws.developer.WSBindingProvider
```

In the debugger, the docManClient object has this toString():

```
   org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler@a460a46
```

This jar is in Websphere-land only, and is not part of my project's .ear file:

```
  C:\dev_tools\server\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\plugins\org.apache.axis2.jar
```

I attempted to change the app config, to prefer its own classes above those of Websphere. 
I used the wsadim tool to change to PARENT_LAST, but this had no affect on the observed behaviour:

```
 set dep [$AdminConfig getid /Deployment:my-ear/]
 set depObject [$AdminConfig showAttribute $dep deployedObject]
 set classldr [$AdminConfig showAttribute $depObject classloader]
 $AdminConfig showall $classldr
 $AdminConfig modify $classldr {{mode PARENT_LAST}}
 $AdminConfig save
 $AdminConfig showall $classldr
```

The app is an .ear which contains a single .war.

EDIT added later: I'm not clear on the relation between jax-ws-rt.jar and axis2.jar. The axis2.jar is not a drop-in replacement for jax-ws-rt.jar: when I switch to axis2.jar, the code no longer compiles.

Comment: Another way to find your own classes first is to put your overlapping jars into a websphere (isolated) shared library.

Comment: It looks like you changed the app classloader, but you also need to change the module classloader to parent last.  I think this can be done in the console.  There's also a jvm property, disablejaxwsengine, or something like that, that might help get WebSphere's jax-ws impl out of the way.

Comment: If you just use plain JAX-WS API, try to remove `jaxws-rt-2.1.4.jar` from your classpath completely, as WebSphere already provides JAX-WS engine. Otherwise you would have to disable internal JAX-WS engine - check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28913923/3701228)